# How do I have zlib output the gzip footer?

Tags: c++, zlib

How do I have zlib output the gzip footer for me?
I'm currently doing it myself but it'd be nice if zlib could do it for me.

```
shared_data xcc_z::gzip(data_ref s)
{
  z_stream stream;
  stream.zalloc = NULL;
  stream.zfree = NULL;
  stream.opaque = NULL;
  if (deflateInit2(&stream, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 16 + MAX_WBITS, MAX_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY))
  {
    assert(false);
    return {};
  }
  shared_data d(deflateBound(&stream, s.size()) + 8);
  stream.next_in = const_cast<unsigned char*>(s.data());
  stream.avail_in = s.size();
  stream.next_out = d.data();
  stream.avail_out = d.size() - 8;
  deflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
  deflateEnd(&stream);
  unsigned char* w = stream.next_out;
    w = write_int_le(4, w, crc32(crc32(0, NULL, 0), s.data(), s.size()));
    w = write_int_le(4, w, s.size());
    return d.substr(0, w - d.data());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it doesn't? Your code appends a useless second trailer after the one already written by zlib.

Comment: My bad, I somehow thought it'd only do the header. Before I was also doing the header myself, I'm not sure when the +16 feature was added. BTW, I also emailed you @ zlib@gzip.org about an unrelated issue, is that address correct? Having a named constant for the 16 might be nice too.